# In Rails, can I order a query by a delegate method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delegates, rails-activerecord

I'm having difficulty ordering a query by a delegate method. I've been tasked with helping upgrade a fairly large Rails 3 application to Rails 4. I've come across this query in an index action.

```
# measurements_controller.rb
def index
  @measurements = Measurement.includes(:identifier).order(:name)
end
```

In Rails 4, I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR: column items.name does not exist LINE 1: ...D (item_names.name LIKE '%') ORDER BY "item...
```

So I took a look at the models and found:

```
# measurement.rb
class Measurement < Item
  ...
end

# item.rb
belongs_to :item, class_name: 'ItemName'
delegate :name, :name=, to: :item

# item_name.rb
# This object has a name column in the database
```

If I'm in the terminal and I have an instance of a `Measurement`, I can easily call the `.name` method and it works great. But when it comes to `.order(:name)`, that does not work due to the column not existing.

I have found one solution, but it seems to defeat the purpose of the delegate method. In the controller, I can change it to:

```
@measurements = Measurement.includes(:item).order('item_names.name')
```

Since I know that `Item` delegates the `name` method to `ItemNames`, I don't think my controller needs to know where it's delegated to.

**Is there a way to keep the existing code and still order by the delegate method?**

Comment: Does changing includes to eager_load help (or adding .references(:identifier) )

Comment: Good tip, I did do some reading on Rails 4 and `.references`. Alas, I attempted both of your suggestions with no luck. I'll try any other suggestions tomorrow morning when I return to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but it requires instantiating all your records first (which will decrease performance).

```ruby
@measurements = Measurement.joins(:item).sort_by &:name
```

This code loads all Measurements and instantiates them and then sorts them by the Ruby method `.name`

**Explanation**

`delegate` only affects instances of your ActiveRecord model. It does not affect your SQL queries.

This line maps directly to a SQL query.

```ruby
Measurement.includes(:item).order(:name)
```

As you have noticed, it looks for a `name` column on the measurements table and doesn't find anything. Your ActiveRecord model instances know that `name` only exists on `identifier`, but your SQL database doesn't know that, so you have to tell it explicitly on which table to find the column.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. I know some changes were made to `includes` in Rails 4. Do you know if that had an impact on this? I did not work on the Rails 3 version of this project, but that code was there (with `.order(:name)`) and they claim all of our tests were passing (including accessing that instance variable correctly).

Comment: Here's an option. When you use `.order` with a symbol (like `:name`), Rails will try to add the table name for you ( `ORDER BY info_items.name`). But, with a string, it will add that string directly into your query. In this specific case, you can use `joins(:identifier).order('name')` whic results in `ORDER BY name`. Since the `name` column doesn't exist on `info_items` but does exist on `info_item_identifiers`, it will work properly. You do need to use joins instead of includes. Note that if you join (or include) any other table with a `name` column, you will get an ambiguous column SQL error