# How do you reference a column name in rails for an associated table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a sorting routine that works well when the column is a regular column in a table. However, it does not work with tables that are a one to many relationship.

The sorting code is in application_helper.rb. The regular columns work fine. I am trying to address what happens for the columns with associtiations.

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)
      if column == 'category' then
        title ||= 'Category'
        column == 'category_id'
        direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
        link_to title, :sort => 'category_id', :direction => direction
    else
        title ||= column.titleize
        direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"
        link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
   end
  end
```

the belongs_to in documents.rb

```
       belongs_to :category, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'category_id'
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => 'Owner', :foreign_key => 'owner_id'
```

The sort def is called by the following in documents/index.html.erb

```
 <th><%= sortable "document_title", "Doc_Title" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "summary", "Summary" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "owner" %></th>
      <th><%= sortable "category", Category %></th>
```

I spent some time trying different variations on the parameters on the URL in the browser such as

> http://localhost:3000/documents?direction=asc&sort=category_id 
>   http://localhost:3000/documents?direction=asc&sort=category_id.name
>   http://localhost:3000/documents?direction=asc&sort=document.category_id.name

to try to figure out what name to use to reference the column. The code as I have it now will sort the column. However, it sorts on the integer id, not the name of  the category

Comment: Consider using [delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28202660/in-rails-can-i-order-a-query-by-a-delegate-method)